# How can I take values from EditText and sum them in array

Tags: android, arrays

I have two `Edit-text` for example. I wanna take the value which the user entered on it. and sum them on `array`.

let say the code like this.

```
EditText oneValue = (EditText)addView.findViewById(R.id.one);
EditText twoValue = (EditText)addView.findViewById(R.id.two);
```

If the user entered `5` in `oneValue`, and `7` in `twoValue`. How can I sum them in array ?

Comment: " How can I sum them in array ?" What exactly do you mean?

Comment: You should look at the documentation before asking questions here. You are just wasting everybody's time by being lazy if you fail to do so. Look here - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html#getText()

Comment: If you are trying to add together numbers then you do not need an Array.

Comment: @npace you broke my heart body. I see every body helpful here. thanx !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by "sum them in array"?
If you want add the 2 values and add the summed value in an array then you can do the following:

```
int[] array = new int[10]; // Any size

int a = Integer.parseInt(oneValue.getText().toString());

int b = Integer.parseInt(twoValue.getText().toString());

int c = a + b;

array[0] = c; // Any position
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want an List of Strings :

```
List<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
array.add(oneValue.getText().toString());
array.add(twoValue.getText().toString());
```

If you need a String[] :

```
String[] array = new String[2];
array[0] = oneValue.getText().toString();
array[1] = twoValue.getText().toString();
```

If you need Integers :

```
Integer[] array = new Integer[2];
try {

    array[0] = Integer.parseInt(oneValue.getText().toString());
    array[1] = Integer.parseInt(twoValue.getText().toString());
} catch (NumberFormatException e){
    // handle number parsing exception (the content of the EditText is not a valid number)
}
```

If you need the actual `5+7` string in an Array :

```
List<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
array.add(oneValue.getText().toString()+ " + " + twoValue.getText().toString());
```

If you need the result of 5+7 added to an array of Integer :

```
List<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>();
array.add(Integer.parseInt(oneValue.getText().toString()) + Integer.parseInt(twoValue.getText().toString()));
```

Comment: Perfect answer. But how can I add values. like `5 + 7` in array. By your way

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not exactly clear to me as to the use of array. If you want to add the values in the two Edit Text's follow the following.

```
int val1 = Integer.valueOf(oneValue.getText().toString());
int val2 = Integer.valueOf(twoValue.getText().toString());
int sum = val1 + val2;
```

This is how you can sum the values from the `EditText`s. I'm not clear about the Array part.

The below code would return a string array of the (text) values.

```
String[] values = new String[]{oneValue.getText().toString(), twoValue.getText().toString()};
return values;
```

Comment: ummmm. I meant if the user entered `5` and `7` I wanna add them. like `5 + 7` in array

Comment: Hello, Why would you need an array if you are going to store the sum?

Comment: Hay. because I have many of `EditText`s not just two.